# Is it possible to change hardware manufacturer name of Linux Server?

Tags: linux, hardware-detection

My Linux server shows a weird manufacturer name:
Dell System5[0000]1[0601]7[8664]8[ ]9[R630 Base]10[2.2.5]11[01.

Is there a way I can change it to remove those extra characters and numbers after 'Dell System'. I am not sure how the manufacturer name got that extra stuff.

The reason I am looking for this change is a tool (third party) is failing due to this manufacturer name.

Comment: Is it failing because of the length of the name or because of the name's content (i.e., the tool isn't compatible with that model)?  Any chance that changing the name will affect anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer name is read from the BIOS (there are a number of ways to do that), so if you can reflash the BIOS with an image containing a different name, you'll have a different name.

Another option would be to have a look at exactly how the third party tool is reading the name, and use `LD_PRELOAD` etc. to hook into this and replace it with a different way, without the need to flash the BIOS.

A third option would be to run the tool in a VM, if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, neither we could replace BIOS of production serves (risky) nor change the third party tool.